# Error on Publishing Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have just tried to publish my project and I am getting the following error:

```
Copying file obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll failed. Could not find file 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'.
```

I am getting it under Debug and Release. I am able to do a Build and the Project runs fine.

I have been able to publish this project before. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by deleting all of the files and folders under obj\Release in Visual Studio.

I then rebuilt the project and published it as normal and everything is working again.

I believe this may have been caused by old references to some of the files which were no longer required by the project.

Hope this helps someone else.